# NERD commenter : How to comment out a range

Tags: vim

I am using [NERD commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)

Let's say that I want to comment out lines from 78 to 172. This is what I do. I calculate the difference. That is 94. put my cursor on line 78 and then I do: 94 , c space

In this way I comment 94 lines starting from line number 78.

I don't like the calculation that I need to do. I was hoping to pass a range something like

78,172  to comment the code from line 78 to 172. Am I missing something.

Looking at the popularity of this plugin, it seems there must be a better way to comment and uncomment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd do (in visual mode) `:78v172G` to select and highlight lines 78 to 172, then just `,c<space>`.

Comment: Love this answer - it works for both commenting and uncommenting text in visual mode

Comment: I also use this method only but even this isn't very efficient. It would have been nice if this plugin supports <count><textobject><motion> syntax, as it can make commenting really fast. So what i mean is like this 5c-/j to toggle comments. I have mapped c-/ to toggle comments. I really miss this feature.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't appear that NERDCommenter supports ranges, so Alex's answer would be correct, but he has a typo - it should be `78GV172G` to select (note - no preceeding `:`), followed by your comment function ( in my case `\cc`).

Comment: I do as you said that the lines are well selected. But how can I use nerdCommenter comment them out. What should I input. Document says `[count]<leader>cc |NERDComComment|`, but I don't know what does each part mean.

Answer (score 3):

Enter Visual mode `<ctrl> + V`, using your arrow keys, highlight the lines you want then `/c<space>` (perhaps you have another key binded for commenting).

Answer (score 1):

**Sexy C comments mode**

Ranges of lines just work by default with visual selection + `<leader>cc`, tested on 2.5.2, as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1375070/895245

But above all, I want to highlight in this answer the "sexy mode" comments with `<leader>cs`, which generates nice C multiline comments.

For example, if you start with:

```
This is a c style sexy comment
So there!
```

then `<leader>cs` from visual selection transforms it into:

```
/* This is a c style sexy comment
 * So there! */
```

And you can also switch to non-compact mode by adding to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDCompactSexyComs = 0
```

which works as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                                         *'NERDCompactSexyComs'*
Values: 0 or 1.
Default 0.

Some people may want their sexy comments to be like this: >
    /* Hi There!
     * This is a sexy comment
     * in c */
<
As opposed to like this: >
    /*
     * Hi There!
     * This is a sexy comment
     * in c
     */
```

Another related format which might be of interest is the "Minimal comment map" accessible with `<leader>cm` and which produces:

```
/* Hi There!
   This is a sexy comment
   in C */
```

I wasn't able to find my preferred style unfortunately:

```
/* Hi There!
 * This is a sexy comment
 * in c
 */
```

so I opened: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues/379