# How to use NERD Commenter for vim -- how to use <Leader> key

Tags: vim

I found the NERD comment plugin for vim, but I don't understand the documentation.  Say I want to comment some code in c/c++ e.g.

```
code line 1  
code line 2
```

becomes

```
/*
code line 1  
code line 2  
*/
```

I have seen other threads on this, but to be honest I don't know what `<leader>` is in the [NERD commenter documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218). When I try the accepted answer in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375031/nerd-commenter-how-to-comment-out-a-range), I end up executing the change command on the selected lines.  What is `<leader>` and, step-by-step, how do I go about commenting lines with `/* */`?

Comment: Also check this for more info on the leader key(s): http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/06.html

Comment: @SantoshKumar Rolled back: With your edit it becomes a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1764263! also note the last bit "and, step-by-step, how do I go about commenting lines with `/* */`?"

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try the built-in help, it's excellent. `:help <Leader>` brings you to the relevant documentation. It's just an identifier for an unused key (by default <kbd>\</kbd>, but many change it to <kbd>,</kbd>) that is recommended for starting any custom mappings.

NERD_commenter defines the `<Leader>cc` mapping, so you'd press (one after the other): <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Note: You don't need to hold down the `<Leader>` key, just press it like any other key, and release it. The only modifier keys that can be pressed together with others are Shift, Ctrl, and Alt.

Answer (score 31):

## Your keyboard is the problem

On many **non-English keyboard layouts,** the backslash `\` is only accessible through an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key combination. This makes the default setting of the `<Leader>` character rather impractical for these non-English keyboard users.

Moreover, `<Leader>` key combinations are subject to a default 1000ms time-out. This can be observed by the disappearance of the `<Leader>` key at the right edge of the command line.
So, non-English keyboard users need to be real quick typists for <kbd></kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to work. Failure to do so, results in an undesired `cc` line change.</kbd>

Here is an example of a German keyboard layout with the backslash-bearing key on the top row, third from right:
[image: German keyboard layout]

#Solution
Non-English keyboard users are advised to **change the `<Leader>` key** from the `\` character to the more accessible <kbd>,</kbd> key. Vim beginners should also consider **a slightly longer 1500ms time-out.** Here is what needs to be added to `~/.vimrc`

```
let mapleader=","
set timeout timeoutlen=1500
```

One final caveat; these **changes only take effect after completely exiting Vim.** Resourcing with `:source $MYVIMRC` will not work!

Done that, one can now use <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>c for commenting with NERD Commenter.

Comment: It also took me a few head scratches to find this one!

Comment: Thanks for the information about needing to exit Vim for the change to take effect.

Comment: not sure about remapping it to , tho as that's actually a really useful movement key
"repeat previous f movement in reverse"

Answer (score 7):

> how do I go about commenting lines with /* */?

Аs is stated in the [documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218):

```
[count]<leader>cm |NERDComMinimalComment| 
Comments the given lines using only one set of multipart delimiters.
```

So, just use

- <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> (if your `<leader>` is <kbd>\</kbd>), or
- <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> (if your `<leader>` is <kbd>,</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

> @IngoKarkatNote: You don't need to hold down the  key, just press it like
>   any other key, and release it.

Completely the wrong advice for the original question!

With NerdCommenter, you DO have to hold down the `<leader>` key. Otherwise, as OP found, you just end up activating 'change' mode instead.

Comment: That's not true. Pressing the keys in quick succession works for me.

Comment: not true you pressing in quick succession works fine